# Not able pass array to view in cakephp v 1.3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

In the index action of my UsersController I want to pass strings and arrays to view, so that my View is render correctly. I don't know what am I doing wrong but my view file is not getting one of my array to view.

```
$users = $this->User->getUsers();

//Setting all variable that are present in layout
$this->set('title_for_layout','Users - Admin');
$page_headings = array("text" => "Users", "clss" => "icon-head");
$this->set('page_heading', $page_headings);
//Ends here

//This is actually going to action view file            
$this->set(compact('users'));
```

My View file Code is like this

`<div><?php echo $page_heading[0]['text']; ?></div>`

`<?php foreach($users as $user){ ?>`

I am able to get $users variable here but noting getting $page_heading.

I am getting this error `Undefined variable: page_heading`.

I have tried everything like these:

`$this->set($page_headings);`

`$this->set(compact('page_headings');`

and yes I have change my variable name in view file also to page_headings after doing above code. I am not able to get it working. Can Please anybody help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And `title_for_layout` gets submitted fine too? It shouldn't make a difference, but what about using a single set call `$this->set(compact('title_for_layout', 'page_heading', 'users'));` ?

Comment: ya.. `title_for_layout` is coming good.. I have tried putting array variables together `$this->set(compact('page_heading','users'));`.. Now I am trying your suggestion.. and ya one more thing my `$page_headings` is in layout file, not in action's view file.. Does that have any effect..??

Comment: @ndm sorry I said wrong about `title_for_layout`. It's also not showing correctly..after trying your suggested code it is showing  users and page_heading both as undefined and also not showing the page title..

Comment: That sounds pretty weird... what's your exact CakePHP Version? And are you doing anything special regarding to layout/view rendering? Something like a custom view class maybe? Have you tried whether the problem replicates with a fresh default CakePHP installation?

Comment: I am working on 1.3.17 version of cakePhp. No I am not doing anything special. May be I should try on fresh installation.

Answer (score 0):

This was happened because I was editing my live server file directly from filezilla's edit option and when I was saving it after editing file, it was somehow becoming the one line code and because of the comment tag all code that I had edited became comments.

I rectified this problem when i took fresh copy from server.

**So what I learned today**: After say working about half an hour on file, take updated file from server if you editing from filezilla because you don't know how it gonna save the file.

Thanks [ndm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1392379/ndm) for your help.